# SHA256 fingerprint from X509Certificate

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ssl-certificate

How to decode the SHA256 fingerprint from X509Certificate in Kotlin without third library usage in hex.

X509Certificate get SHA256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the MessageDigest from Java Security API

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate

fun decodeSHA256Fingerprint(cert: X509Certificate): String {
    val sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    val fingerprint = sha256.digest(cert.encoded)
    return fingerprint.joinToString(separator = "") { String.format("%02x", it) }
}
```